# Aws codepipeline (BeforeInstall)

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

Message CodeDeploy agent was not able to receive the lifecycle event. Check the CodeDeploy agent logs on your host and make sure the agent is running and can connect to the CodeDeploy server.

I AM role:AmazonEC2RoleforAWSCodeDeploy -> attached target -ec2 AWSCodeDeployRole -> Added pipeline deploy. target -ec2 -> installation codedeployagent working good. Status running.

/var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent: No Error
[Pipeline Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSb9R.jpg)

I AM role:AmazonEC2RoleforAWSCodeDeploy -> attached target -ec2 AWSCodeDeployRole -> Added pipeline deploy. target -ec2 -> installation codedeployagent working good. Status running.

Also tried restarted,
Other simple Pipeline works below link same, It's working same for me.
https://youtu.be/531i-n5FMRY?si=KEdaxMEPr3_yq-j6

/var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent:

But still i am getting this error? I tried a lot.?

https://repost.aws/questions/QUhNd2_SC5RXuGtlwQbV2kXg#ANLrBbPNShRCGiwLwr9EuO0g

Also tried repost. Still not working.